# MTJ 1.1.2 plugin couldn't be installed on Eclipse Juno (4.2)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mtj

MTJ (Mobile Tools For Java, a famous J2ME plugin for Eclipse) 1.1.2 couldn't be installed on Eclipse Juno (4.2).
I use the following update url to install the plugin:

```
Mobile Tools For Java - http://download.eclipse.org/mtj/updates/1.1.2/stable/
```

But it failed to be installed with dependency error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Mobile Tools for Java 1.1.2.201101310801 (org.eclipse.mtj.feature.group 1.1.2.201101310801)
>     Missing requirement: MTJ Core Plug-in 1.2.1.201101310801 (org.eclipse.mtj.core 1.2.1.201101310801) requires 'bundle org.mortbay.jetty.server [6.1.0,7.0.0)' but it could not be found
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Mobile Tools for Java 1.1.2.201101310801 (org.eclipse.mtj.feature.group 1.1.2.201101310801)
>       To: org.eclipse.mtj.core [1.2.1.201101310801]

Does anyone know what's the problem of this?

I try to find a plugin containing the bundle "org.mortbay.jetty.server [6.1.0,7.0.0)", but not found.

Answer (score 4):

If you read these release notes you will find the key:

http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/jme-sdk-3.2/release-notes/pdf/release-notes.pdf

Install the MTJ toolkit.

1. Go to Help > Install New Software.
2. In the “Work with” field, enter this URL: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
3. Click Add. When the plugins are discovered, open the Mobile and Device Development Tools 
   hierarchy and check Mobile Tools for Java Examples and Mobile Tools for Java SDK. Click Next.On the installation screen select all plugins and click Finish then click OK.
4. A Juno plugin named org.eclipse.jetty.server_.jar conflicts with the MTJ libraries when the plugin version is higher than 6. If it is you must prevent it from loading by changing its name so the Jar file is
   not parsed. Locate the file in your Juno installation’s \plugins directory and change the extension from .jar to something else.
   For example, change it to: org.eclipse.jetty.server_.old

Comment: This worked for me in Eclipse Kepler. Note that doing #4 is not enough ... at least when I was installing JME SDK 3.4, I still got a dependency error for the deviceselector. But when I used the plugins listed in #3 from Indigo, the error went away.

Answer (score 3):

here is the indigo update site http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/ . FFF is right just install plugin from indigo, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

"Eclipse Juno" chapter on [JAVA ME page on Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/sdk/index.html) states:

> A Juno plugin named org.eclipse.jetty.server_(version).jar conflicts with the MTJ libraries when the plugin version is higher than 6. If it is you must prevent it from loading by changing its name so the Jar file is not parsed. For example, change it to: org.eclipse.jetty.server.old

Worked for me.

Comment: Hi, could you tell me how to do this please. how do you rename plugins?

Answer (score 1):

add indigo repo, it'll install but still a no go
recommend using older version if you need it